# Without a home to return to or without a home to return?

Tags: american-english

We say :

" I'm going home "

but not

" I'm going to home "

So which is correct between :

" Someone without a home to return to "

or

" Someone without a home to return "

I know I can just say homeless, but I'm practicing for the IELTS, if I can cram more words to say absolutely nothing, I should do it ( my professor recommends it )

Comment: Both are grammatical but they mean very different things. Which is ‘correct’ depends on what you’re trying to say.

Comment: The second one, without the _to_, means that _a home_ is the direct object of _return_ -- i.e, it means 'someone without a home that they can give back to someone else'. The _return to_ is a different verb phrase, with an intransitive meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are talking about. Usually if you say "return" or "go" with a destination as an object you usually follow it with the preposition "to", as in "I'm going to the cinema" or "I'll return to work". In the case of the word "home" you often don't need the preposition to:

- I'm going home.
- I'll have to go home.
- I'll return home.
- I'll have to return home.

I'm not sure what the reason for this is. I guess "home" is a special word.

So you're asking, given that it seems you don't need to use the preposition "to" with home as your destination, can you say something like:

- I have no home to go <s>to</s>.
  and
- I have no home to return <s>to</s>. (which because "return" is also transitive can also mean something completely different, like returning your home, maybe to your mortgagee/parents etc.)

You can't omit "to" in constructions like these. Why, I'm not sure, but if I happen to find out I'll add to this answer. I have a feeling that in the first set of examples the sentences imply there is one specific and definite home, whereas using a word like "no", which can be seen as a determiner, may make "home" indefinite. Though I'm not sure about this.